# Convert Longitude / Latitude coordinates to Lambert conformal conic projection

Tags: r, maps

I am not an expert with maps and coordinate systems. I need to convert longitude and latitude coordinates into LCC (Lambert conformal conic projection). I have a list of city coordinates that I need to plot in a map. The problem is that the projection of the map is `"+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"`.

What can I do so that the longitude and latitude coordinates are converted into the projection of the map?

Below a `tibble` with the cities and the coordinates:

```
cities <- tibble(city.name = c('Lisbon', 'Barcelona', 'Brussels'),
                 lon = c(-9.139337,2.173404,4.351710),
                 lat = c(38.72225,41.38506,50.85034))
```

How can I convert these coordinates into coordinates according to the projection of the map?

```
"+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sf` package, which has `sf::st_transform()`. This projects the coordinates in an `sf` object.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

cities <- tibble(city.name = c('Lisbon', 'Barcelona', 'Brussels'),
                 lon = c(-9.139337,2.173404,4.351710),
                 lat = c(38.72225,41.38506,50.85034))

city_proj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"

cities <- st_as_sf(cities, coords = c(2, 3))
st_crs(cities) <- 4326
cities <- st_transform(cities, crs = city_proj)

ggplot(cities) + 
  geom_sf()
```

Edit: Changed initial CRS to a standard one. This makes the transformation make more sense.

Comment: The cities tibble needs to be set to a suitable projection first before transformation. So something like this `st_crs(cities) <- "EPSG:4326"`.